# React. Set input data from parent to input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is all my code: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rpktr8)

I tryed do this:

```
state = {
    valueTitle: '',
    valueText: ''
}

titleHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        valueTitle: e.target.value
    })
}

textHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        valueText: e.target.value
    })
}
```

This string created by clicking, so the method fire after click

```
<String 
    key={this.state.stringKey} 
    textFieldTitle={(e) => this.titleHandler(e)}
    textFieldText={(e) => this.textHandler(e)}
    valueTitle={this.state.valueTitle}
    valueText={this.state.valueText}
 />
```

String component

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                placeholder="Введите заголовок"
                type="text"
                className={classes.String}
                value={this.props.valueTitle}
                // onChange={(e) => this.titleHandler(e)}
                onChange={this.props.textFieldTitle}
            />
            <input
                placeholder="Введите текст"
                type="text"
                className={classes.String}
                value={this.props.valueText}
                // onChange={(e) => this.textHandler(e)}
                onChange={this.props.textFieldText}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I write smt in inputs nothing happened, why? But if I hardcode in valueTitle or valueText the inputs have data

Comment: Try `textFieldTitle={this.titleHandler}` and `textFieldText={this.textHandler}` instead.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Works with bug. 
When I write smt in inputs - nothing, when I clicked to add new string then new string created with my text but only the last character
http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/09/14/0014/0699/975547/47/b3f009b0bd.jpg

Comment: You need to update your question to add the code that adds new `String` components that you are referring to. In my answer, there is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5sx6zx) that you can fork and add your additional code. Thanks!

Comment: Is your component name really `String`? Because JS also has global String function

Comment: I added my code on StackBlitz in the top of the question, you can check there

Comment: @poma your approach is wrong to keep the compoents in the array.. Rather you keep the value in a list.. I'll write it.

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-scvc2j , [app](https://react-scvc2j.stackblitz.io)